# AngularJS - HTTP GET request with status code 302

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

I am building a RESTful API using AngularJS, and i got stuck. I am trying to send a GET request which will fetch me a `User` with given `username`. Here is the code:

```
var loginModule = angular.module('login-module', []);


    loginModule
        .factory('loginService',['$http','$rootScope', function($http){

            var factoryMethods = {};
            factoryMethods.login = function(username){
                return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/WebProjekat/webapi/users/'+username);
            }
            factoryMethods.setLoggedUser = function(user){
                $rootScope.loggedUser = user;
            }
            return factoryMethods;
        }])
        .controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http','loginService', function ($scope, $http, loginService){
                $scope.username = '';
                $scope.password = '';

                $scope.user = {};

                $scope.userLogin = function(){
                    loginService.login($scope.username)
                            .then(function(response){

                                console.log("User :" +angular.toJson(response.data)+"successfully logged in!");
                                $scope.user = response.data;
                                loginService.setLoggedUser($scope.user);

                            },function(error){

                                console.log("Error occured durring user authentication!");

                            });
                }

        }]);
```

For some reason the promise produced by this function:

```
factoryMethods.login = function(username){
                    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/WebProjekat/webapi/users/'+username);
                }
```

gets rejected, and the status code i get is 302. What i do not understand is why did redirection happen,and why was the data mapped to a second callback function which is called when promise gets rejected.

I followed the flow of the execution, and Jersey Servlet successfully finds the `UserResource` class and the service that it needs to call in order to GET the user with the given username. Here is the Java code:

```
/**
     * URL: http://localhost:8030/WebProjekat/webapi/users/{userId}
     * @param username - identification of some user that is registered on the system
     * @param uriInfo - variable which can manipulate URL
     * @return user with the given username
     * @throws JsonParseException
     * @throws JsonMappingException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("userId") String username, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        User user = new User();

        List<User> listOfUsers = userService.getAllUsers();
        if((user = userService.getUser(username, listOfUsers))!=null) {


            user.addLink(getUserSectionsUri(uriInfo, user), "sections");
            user.addLink(getSelfUri(uriInfo, user), "self");

            return Response.status(Status.FOUND)
                            .entity(user)
                            .build();
        }

        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
                       .build();
    }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should return Status.OK (200) instead of Status.FOUND (302) in the servlet

Comment: Oh! This is so embarrassing :D Thank you so much i have no idea what i was looking at!

Comment: No embarrasment mate, it is just the effect of new eyes looking at it. Happened to me many times =)